# display korean language using database oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I will display the text from the database but the text is written using Korean language, when I select the data, the data is only showing a character like this "¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿".
so, what should i do ??
I will display the text by using PHP on my web.

Thank You.

Comment: Is it the character set UTF-8

Comment: my character in oracle already set  UTF-8

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET%';`? `UTF-8` does not exist on Oracle, it is either `UTF8` or `AL32UTF8`. What is the data type of the column? Do you get proper output when you select the table using TOAD or SQL Developer?

Comment: i already run that query and result is UTF-8, and the type column is varchar and i using Toad...
NLS_CHARACTERSET UTF8, 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: Then I assume the problem is on the PHP side, not on Oracle.

Comment: can you tell me about setting in php for solving my problem??? 
because I don't know much about php settings..

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to enable Unicode as per the [Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch5.htm).

A little bit of googling would've helped you, [here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239250/how-to-configure-utf8-character-set-in-oracle). But before that, if you already have data in it, you have to read this notes on how to convert DB to Unicode:

Changing the Database Character Set - a short overview Doc ID: 225912.1

The National Character Set in Oracle 9i, 10g and 11g Doc ID: 276914.1

Changing Database Character Set - Valid Superset Definitions Doc ID: 119164.1

Comment: Posting just a few Metalinks is not an answer