# Oracle database migration to UTF- 8 standard from ISO-8859-15

Tags: database, oracle, utf-8, migration, database-migration

I want to migrate the exsisitng database to UTF - 8 standard from 
ISO-8859-1.

Additional info: LANGUAGE=GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8ISO8859P15.

I have to create the new database which acceptes the UTF - 8.

1)How to create the database with the UTF - 8? Where to change the configuration?

2) The old database data in the format of ISO-8859-1. When I move a data from old database to new databse how to change data to the UTF - 8 format from ISO-8859-1?

Comment: For a detailed description have a look at this document: [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm)

Comment: Can you please answer me for 2nd question that I aksed for?

Comment: It should be described in linked document.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see in this post :
[How to configure UTF8 character set in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239250/how-to-configure-utf8-character-set-in-oracle)

In the reponse, Mark J. Bobak describes 2 cases and gives each a solution. One of this cases seems to be yours.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Can you please provide the answer for the second question?