# Saving Telugu text to Oracle DB with Java

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm looking for help in saving data in Telugu to an Oracle DB with Java.

I need to generate a message to consumer in this language and save it in the DB and then send the message via SMS. The SMS triggering in done for English but for I need to add it for Telugu.
Sample text is as follows:
విద్యుత్ బకాయిలు కట్టినందుకు ధన్యవాదములు

Comment: I tried that for Hindi(devnagri) couple of months back..could not find anything

Comment: @OP: check if oracle is configured with _**AL32UTF8**_ for _**NLS_CHARACTERSET**_. Unless which, such input may result a garbage.

Comment: @OP: this answer on SO may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8239447/767881

Comment: @srini ... have you completed this

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be converting the telugu or any unicode text into hexadecimal format with UCS2 tag 81. Then save the complete data as normal english string because hexadecimal contains 0-9 and A-F characters.

Hope this will help. :-)